# Why is my codepen not being implemented to my website correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**First try:**

I implemented [My pen code](https://codepen.io/jens-johnston/full/WLKrrg) on a page but nothing happened (page was blank). I made separate a JS-sheet for my sober child theme and it worked correctly when I tried to make an alert, but when implementing the desired JS-code nothing happend.

**Second try:**

The second time i Implemented all JS and HTML as RAW elements from wp-bakery, and yet nothing happened.

What should I do to make this code work?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jens-johnston/full/WLKrrg)

```
    $('.window').draggable();
$('.icon').draggable();

$('.cancel, .close').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $('.window').hide();
});

$('.ok').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('on');
  $('.power-button').fadeIn();
});

$('.start-btn').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.start-menu').toggleClass('open');
});


$('.windows-update').on('click', function(){
  $('.overlay').addClass('on');
  $('.start-menu').removeClass('open');
  $('.start-btn').removeClass('active');
  $('.window').hide();
  $('.power-button').hide();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.desktop').addClass('windowsXP');
    $('.overlay').removeClass('on');
    }, 3000);
});


$('.turn-on-computer').on('click', function(){
  $('.power-button').addClass('on');
  $('.window').hide();
  $('.start-menu').removeClass('open');
  $('.start-btn').removeClass('active');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.power-button').removeClass('on');
    $('.power-button').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.overlay').removeClass('on');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add jquery and jquery ui to your website?

Comment: Hello, I did not why would that help and is there a toutorial for it?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Jquery ui and jquery are the libraries used in that pen. They are required to make that pen work. If you go to the pen and look in settings under javascript you will see the javascript libraries used.